# evaluate formula given by AST multiple times

Tags: c++

I want to evaluate a formula multiple times that is given by a AST node.
for example

result = a*y - b*x

a,b are constants and x,y are variables that change over time.

```
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <apply>
          <minus/>
          <apply>
            <times/>
            <ci> a </ci>
            <ci> y </ci>
          </apply>
          <apply>
            <times/>
            <ci> b </ci>
            <ci> x </ci>
          </apply>
        </apply>
      </math>
```

I've written a recursive function ( double evaluateAST(x,y) ), that reads the AST, substitutes the values of constants and variables and calculates the result.
BUT as i want to evaluate the formula very often, this is a very slow solution.

I would like to prefer a solution, where I evaluate the AST once and get a function like

```
double f(x,y){return VALUE_OF_a*y - VALUE_OF_b*x}
```

I'm new to C++ but I found the Lambda function. 
Is this a solution to my problem?

```
auto result  = [](double x, double y){return evaluateAST(x,y)}
```

I'm not sure if this solution works, because I'm afraid that I evaluate the function evaluateAST(x,y) as often as I call the lambda function.

Did I missunderstood the lambda functions?
Are there better solutions for my problem?

Comment: Look up "memoization". If you memorize the call to your eval function, you can probably get a big speedup.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know this technique but does it work, if my variables change. If I understood it correctly it will just memorize calculations that have been done and won't repeat the same calculation with the same values.

Comment: Ya, basically. Languages like Clojure have built-ins that you give a function to, and they automatically memoize the function. I don't think c++ had such a function, so you'll need to write your own.

Comment: Note though that you'll need a way of determining if the input is the same, which will likely require traversing the entire AST once to hash it or something. Make sure that that's still more efficient than just reevaluating it.